# Send value to function through chain inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to pass an array to a function through a chain? I came across a JavaScript test for a job that proposed this is possible.  Is it?

```
var hereIsArray = [13,27,49,57];

function printArray() {
  // insert code here to print array...
  // this may read the parent of the chain,  or the variable placed before the function in the chain.
};

hereIsArray.printArray();
```

I am familiar with passing variables into a function in between the parenthesis and would be the way I would do it.

Below is a copy of what the test (question #5) is asking for. "assignment.log" is a function they created to check the output. You can see the answer they are scouting for.

```
//#5 write code so that console logs print out true
//   add(addValue) should return a new arrays where addValue
//   is added to each value of original array
//   i.e. [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

// [your code goes here]



var e = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

assignment.log(e.add(5) == '[6,7,8,9,10]', 5);

var d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

assignment.log(d.add(10) == '[11,12,13,14,15]', 5);
```

Comment: Yes, it's called prototype chaining

Comment: Yeah, you can use `prototype`, but JavaScript can convert Arrays  to Strings with `.toString()`, so what's the point?

Comment: If you're using JavaScript to do math you'll want to multiply by Math.pow(10, 17) on each number then add or subtract before dividing by the same number, if doing addition or subtraction when working with decimals.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Array.prototype.printArray = function(){
  return '['+this.toString()+']';
}
var ary = [0, 5, 7, 25];
console.log(ary.printArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple and straight answer to the job test is:

```
Array.prototype.add = function (amount) {
    return "[" + this.map(item => item + amount).toString() + "]";
};
```

One could also explain what a `prototype` is and how it helps with attaching things to instances of that type (your main question), but... if I were you, I would present the interviewer with a few suggestions for improvement first:

- change `add()` to some better name (`addToAll()`, perhaps?), or maybe break it into one function that adds that amount to every item and another that converts it into a string;
- do not use `var`. It's 2017 and we have `const` (see [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/274352/152836));
- extending (a.k.a. "attaching things to") native prototypes is considered bad practice (see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes)), so I would suggest creating a helper function instead; moreover, what would happen if you have an array of things that are not numbers and try to call that method? It wouldn't work as expected, so that's another good reason not to attach it to the `Array` prototype;
- I would also note that `==` in the assert should be replaced by `===`, which is considered good practice (see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Strict_equality_using)).

Interviews are all about surprising your interviewer. Maybe they weren't just looking for the plain, obvious answer (which is pretty simple, actually), but were looking for someone who would point out what was wrong about the code presented. I love confronting my interviewees with some bad code to see how they will react. A good programmer (the one you want to hire) will **kindly** suggest improving what was asked.